# javascript creating a object to print a array object

Tags: javascript

Im a newbie to javascript and trying to print a create a object that contains a array and print the array,
When I try to run this code, I get a error in console - syntax error missing ; near "var person-1"

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
        </script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                function person(fname,lname,kids){
                    this.firstname = fname;
                    this.lastname = lname;
                    this.kids = kids;
                    this.displaykids = function displaykids(){
                        this.kids.forEach(function(kid){
                            console.log(kid);
                        })
                    }
                }
                var person-1 = person('Bob','Marley',['Bill','Mike','Tom'])
                console.log(person.firstname)
            })
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        This is the body
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can't have a `-` in a variable name.  P.S. that should be `new person('Bob', ...`.

Comment: Thanks..I fixed it but still when I print person.firstname..it prints undefined..

Comment: `person` is the name of the class, not your instance.  You need to name your instance something else and use that variable name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var person-1 = person('Bob','Marley',['Bill','Mike','Tom'])
```

Two things wrong here.  One: you can't have a `-` in a variable.  Two: you forgot the `new`.

It should be:

```
var person1 = new person('Bob','Marley',['Bill','Mike','Tom']);
console.log(person1.firstname);
```